# Is possible to create a new column of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I want to create a new column according to the column A & column B.

Column A

1

2

3

Column B

A

B

C

New Column

1:A

2:B

3:C

How can I do that in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's quite a simple process. Using the Attribute Table you can add the column and then use the Field Calculator to update your new column

- Open the attribute table
- Start editing (button on the far left)
- Open field calculator

  - Field name - whatever you want
  - Field type - text
  - Expression: "Column A" || ':' || "Column B"

(Qgis 2.0.1)